# Targeting every fourth item of a list/array with Twig

Tags: arrays, list, count

I'd like to apply a CSS class of `.fourth` to every fourth item in a list of `<li>`'s, but cannot for the life of me figure it out. As far as I know, Batch and Slice don't work in Stacey v3's version of Twig.

Here's my code:

```
{% for child in child.children %}
    <li class="project-child half col {{ child.id }}{% if loop.index is even %} end{% endif %}{% if loop.last %} last{% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ child.url }}" alt="{{ child.title }}">
            {% if child.images %}
                {# This finds the first image and resizes it, simple. #}
                {% for image in child.images if loop.first %}
                        <figure class="project-thumbnail">
                            <img src="{{ resize_path( image.url, '490', '', '4:3', 95) }}" alt="{{ child.title }}" width="{{ child.image.width }}" height="{{ child.image.height }}">
                        </figure>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <h2 class="thumbnail-title">{{ child.title }}</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And behind the .last class I'd like to add .fourth. It's a shame I can't figure out how to count every fourth item, when finding the first, last, odd and even item is straightforward.

My logic was this `{% if loop.index == 4 %} fourth{% endif %}`, which only added it to the first occurrence of the fourth item in the list, rather than every fourth.

Comment: Could you paste us some code to see it in action ? Are the li generated with a for loop, are they hardcoded ? This could help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So let me understand, you want to add a class to your `<h2 class="thumbnail-title">{{ child.title }}</h2>` every 4 children ? Am I right ?

Then you could try: `<h2 class="thumbnail-title {% if (loop.index % 4) == 0 %}myFourthClass{% endif %}">{{ child.title }}</h2>`

Comment: @Einenlum Ah I meant for `<li class="project-child half col end">`, but that works anyway! Thanks a bunch! Could you explain the logic of the code so I may understand how to use it in future for other situations? :)

Comment: Sure ! The % is a "modulo" operator. It calculates the rest of a division between two integers. So `10 % 3 = 1`, because `10/3 = 3` and it remains `1`. In your case you want to apply something to every fourth item so you use `loop.index % 4`: It will select situations where loop.index is divisible by `4`. More info on modulo here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: If this is "solved", please indicate so by posting an answer, not editing your title.